# Two sums and three tables in one SQLite query

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, count, aggregate-functions

I have three tables: activities, actions (each action is one execution of an activity) and photos (each action can have attached photos).

Here is [an SQL Fiddle for this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/ff4ec/12/0).

Now I want to retrieve activities in descending order and for each activity I want total time spent on it and total photos attached to it. Order of an activity calculated using the the stop time of it's last action.

For example, for the following data

```
activities
------------------
 _id |   title
------------------
   1 | Activity 1
   2 | Activity 2
   3 | Activity 3
   4 | Activity 4

actions
-------------------------------------------------------------
_id | activity_id |    date_started     |     date_stopped
-------------------------------------------------------------
  1 |           1 | 2014-01-23 20:45:03 | 2014-01-23 20:45:24
  2 |           2 | 2014-01-23 20:45:27 | 2014-01-23 20:45:29
  3 |           3 | 2014-01-23 20:45:31 | 2014-01-23 20:45:43
  4 |           1 | 2014-01-23 20:45:46 | 2014-01-23 20:45:48
  5 |           4 | 2014-01-23 20:45:50 | 2014-01-23 20:46:19

photos
--------------------------------------------------------
_id | action_id |      date_taken     |     path
--------------------------------------------------------
  1 |         1 | 2014-01-23 20:45:11 | 758712034.jpg
  2 |         1 | 2014-01-23 20:45:21 | 537444469.jpg
  3 |         3 | 2014-01-23 20:45:39 | 28884579.jpg
  4 |         5 | 2014-01-23 20:45:58 | 1519722792.jpg
  5 |         5 | 2014-01-23 20:46:08 | 298808374.jpg
  6 |         5 | 2014-01-23 20:46:15 | 2059925529.jpg
```

I was hoping to get required data with this query:

```
SELECT
    activityId, title, sum(seconds) AS totalSeconds, sum(cnt) AS totalPhotos 
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            activities._id AS activityId, activities.title AS title,
            actions._id AS actionId,
            strftime("%s", ifnull(actions.date_stopped, 'now')) -
            strftime("%s", actions.date_started) AS seconds,
            count(photos._id) AS cnt
        FROM
            activities JOIN actions ON activities._id = actions.activity_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN photos ON photos.action_id = actions._id
        GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
        ORDER BY actionId DESC
    )
GROUP BY 1
```

But, unfortunately, it gives this result:

```
activityId |   title    | totalSeconds | totalPhotos 
--------------------------------------------------------
         1 | Activity 1 |           23 |           2
         2 | Activity 2 |            2 |           0
         3 | Activity 3 |           12 |           1
         4 | Activity 4 |           29 |           3
```

and I am trying to get this (see the order of `activity_id` in actions table):

```
activityId |   title    | totalSeconds | totalPhotos 
--------------------------------------------------------
         4 | Activity 4 |           29 |           3
         1 | Activity 1 |           23 |           2
         3 | Activity 3 |           12 |           1             
         2 | Activity 2 |            2 |           0
```

How can I change my query in order to get what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(**THANK YOU** for setting up an SQL Fiddle.  This makes things easier).

You're heading in the right direction - potentially, all you have to add is `ORDER BY totalSeconds DESC` to the end of your query.  However, your query has a couple of issues, and would probably be better something along these lines:

```
SELECT Activities._id, Activities.title, Actions.totalSeconds, Actions.totalPhotos
FROM Activities
JOIN (SELECT Actions.activity_id, 
             SUM(STRFTIME("%s", COALESCE(Actions.date_stopped, 'now')) 
                            - STRFTIME("%s", Actions.date_started)) AS totalSeconds, 
             SUM(COALESCE(Photos.photoCount, 0)) as totalPhotos,
             MAX(COALESCE(Actions.date_stopped, DATETIME('now'))) as mostRecent
      FROM Actions
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT action_id, COUNT(*) as photoCount
                 FROM Photos
                 GROUP BY action_id) Photos
             ON Photos.action_id = Actions._id
      GROUP BY Actions.activity_id) Actions
   ON Actions.activity_id = Activities._id
ORDER BY Actions.mostRecent DESC
```

(and the [working result fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/ff4ec/27))

Specifically:

1. You were grouping by all columns (in the inner query).  In situations like that you either want `DISTINCT` (conceptually/logically), or it's better to change the query to be aggregated smaller.  Note that by aggregating by tables like I have here, indices are more likely to be used.
2. You were grouping by numbered columns: always spell out which columns you want.  In extreme cases, if someone changes the ordering of columns in the `SELECT` list but *not* the `GROUP BY`, your results may change... in ways you don't expect, and will **not** receive errors for.
3. Your inner query had an `ORDER BY`.  This is quite unnecessary, and is forcing the engine to do extra work.
4. Your outer `GROUP BY` only referenced one column, but there was one column un-aggregated/grouped.  It was giving correct results in this case, but it's a dangerous feature; if there was more than one value possible, which one is chosen is undeterminable.  Avoid this by default.
5. Prefer SQL Standard functions where available (unless for specific performance reasons) - `IFNULL()` isn't on all platforms, but `COALESCE` *is*.  Barring the date/time math (which is usually RDBMS dependent anyways), this query would work on all platforms.

(as an aside, I'm annoyed by SQLite's lack of date/time/timestamp types, but as that's hardly your fault...)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out to issues in the query. They are sound justified to me. Unfortunately, I think ordering by `Actions.totalSeconds` is wrong. It does give the required result for the test data but duration of an action or activity is not related to the order. The time when activity was stopped is related (last stopped should be first in results)

Comment: So you know, that's the first time you've given what the ordering should be by; this is why both @Ondemannen and I gave the answers we did.  Updating answer.

Comment: I did say "Order of an activity calculated using the the stop time of it's last action.", but probably it was not that evident. Anyway, thank you for the update, it fixed the issue. And you not only solved the issue but also gave some great advises. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    activityId, title, sum(seconds) AS totalSeconds, sum(cnt) AS totalPhotos 
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            activities._id AS activityId, activities.title AS title,
            actions._id AS actionId,
            strftime("%s", ifnull(actions.date_stopped, 'now')) -
            strftime("%s", actions.date_started) AS seconds,
            count(photos._id) AS cnt
        FROM
            activities JOIN actions ON activities._id = actions.activity_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN photos ON photos.action_id = actions._id
        GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
        ORDER BY actionId DESC
    )
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY seconds DESC;
```

Returns:

```
4|Activity 4|29|3
1|Activity 1|23|2
3|Activity 3|12|1
2|Activity 2|2|0
```

But I may have misread the question since the only thing I added was the **ORDER BY seconds DESC** line. If you change from seconds to **cnt** then you'll receive the same result.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not correct. Seconds absolutely not related to the order I want to get.

Comment: How about changing *seconds* to *cnt*?

Comment: They are unrelated to the order too.

Comment: Would it be easier if you added the date_stopped as a column in the inner select and the get MAX(date_stopped) in the outer select?